# Can I store product manufacturing data and a ULR into the same QR code?

Tags: design, database, web, qr-code

I'm manufacturing a product that I will be selling to retailers throughout the United States. I want to be able to track the products manufacturing date, who we sold that batch of production too, and some other data in the QR code so if I ever get a product warranty claim I'll be able to pull up all that data. I also want to use the QR code as a marketing tool.  I want the QR code to function in a way that if it's scanned by a customer it'll pull up our website and if I scan it I'm also able to pull up all the product manufacturing data.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can put any text into a QR code. If you make the text look like a url, for example bendersqrreader://etc then you can for example write an iPhone app that will be automatically opened if you scan the qr code, and I expect the same is true for Android.

To automatically launch a website, I think you just start the text in th the QR  with https://www.mywebsite.com/etc. If you want website + app you put a link on that website.